# Displaying 2 divs besides each other using the full width of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I want to display two `divs` besides each other and using the full width of the parent `div`. My Problem is when i set the left width to *25%* and the right `div` to *75%* the second `div` is getting wrapped in the next line. When i use *25%* and *74%* it is working but its not using the whole width of the parent `div`.

Can someone help me?

```html
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
        <div style="width:25%;display: inline-block;">
            <span style="vertical-align: super;"><b>Anmerkungen:</b></span>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 74%;display: inline-block;">
            <div style="border-bottom-color:black;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px;width:100%"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I also had made some pictures but i cant display them cause stackoverflow is telling me that my post contains code without code indent. Pictures in the first comment

Comment: [Wrong layout with 25% and 75%](https://i.imgur.com/Vy5YNi7.png)
[html text](https://i.imgur.com/9xka89p.png)
[Right layout but not using the whole width 25% and 74%](https://i.imgur.com/Y4g5FRM.png)

Comment: Use `float: left;`instead of `display: inline-block;` for the div "Anmerkung"

Comment: @GucciBananaKing99 That thing with font-size: 0 works. Sry for useless question